# Angular 7 Render dynamic component based on json input

Tags: angular

This is my json input, based on the selector given in the json, I want to render the component within the below-given template

## JSON Input:

```
    {
    "selector":"ngx-calendar"
    };
```

**Angular Template:**

```
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-sm-6"> 
   < {{ JSON INPUT SELECTOR }} ></{{ JSON INPUT SELECTOR  }}>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would imply that you have those components in your code, so you could do it like `<div *ngIf="component === 'nxg-calendar'"><ngx-calendar></ngx-calendar></div>`

Comment: if I have 30+ components then how can I proceed

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts if you do not have the components. I don't think you can easily just write strings into tagnames...

Comment: Here is another one: http://www.gistia.com/angular-dynamic-components/

Comment: Thanks, mate it may help